# XSLT Processor on browser doesn't perform the transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transform, processor

I used a XSLT Processor found on Internet to transform a XML file in a HTML file.
It worked, but when i try to do the same thing on a browser, adding to the XML file the reference `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="contabilità.xsl"?>` , it doesn't work.
I tried with Firefox, Chrome and Edge and the result is the same.
This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="contabilità.xsl"?>

<gruppo>
    <nome>Casa Miles</nome>
    <studente>
        <id>sergio</id>
        <nome>sergio</nome>
        <cognome>zavota</cognome>
        <scontrino>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>sapone piatti</nome>
                <quantità>1</quantità>
                <costo>3.3</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>bresaola</nome>
                <quantità>1</quantità>
                <costo>5.5</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>pasta</nome>
                <quantità>10</quantità>
                <costo>0.5</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>pane</nome>
                <quantità>3</quantità>
                <costo>1.4</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <data>2020-02-10</data>
            <pagato>true</pagato>
        </scontrino>
        <pagamenti>
            <partecipante>
                <id>Stefano</id>
                <quota>-33.0</quota>
            </partecipante>
        </pagamenti>
    </studente>
    <studente>
        <id>stefano</id>
        <nome>stefano</nome>
        <cognome>Silvestri</cognome>
        <scontrino>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>shampoo</nome>
                <quantità>2</quantità>
                <costo>2.3</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>insalata</nome>
                <quantità>4</quantità>
                <costo>0.5</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>hamburger</nome>
                <quantità>1</quantità>
                <costo>3.6</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>pane</nome>
                <quantità>3</quantità>
                <costo>1.4</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <data>2020-03-10</data>
            <pagato>true</pagato>
        </scontrino>
        <pagamenti>
            <partecipante>
                <id>Sergio</id>
                <quota>33.0</quota>
            </partecipante>
        </pagamenti>
    </studente>
</gruppo>
```

This is the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="tableByDataScontrino" match="scontrino" use="data" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>HTML Document</title>

            </head>

            <style>
                table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
                }

                td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
                }

                tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                }   

                caption {
                display: table-caption;
                text-align: center;
                }

            </style>

            <body  onload="getCurrentData(); getProductPrize()">

                <h2 align="center">Benvenuto <xsl:value-of select="gruppo/studente[nome='sergio']/nome"/></h2>
                <h2 align="center">Gruppo: <xsl:value-of select="gruppo/nome"/> </h2>
                <h2 align="center">Scontrini</h2>

                <xsl:for-each select="gruppo/studente/scontrino[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tableByDataScontrino',data)[1])]">
                    <table>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="pagato = true">
                              <xsl:attribute name="value">1</xsl:attribute>
                              <xsl:attribute name="checked">unchecked</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                              <xsl:attribute name="value">0</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        </input>
                        <label for="pagato"> Pagato</label>
                        <caption style="font-weight: bold;">Data: <xsl:value-of select="data"/></caption>

                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th> 
                            <th>Quantità</th>
                            <th>Costo</th>
                            <th>Totale</th>
                            <th>Partecipanti</th>       
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('tableByDataScontrino',data)/prodotto">
                            <xsl:sort select="data" /> 
                            <tr class="prodotto">
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="nome"/></td>
                                <td class="quantità"><xsl:value-of select="quantità"/></td>
                                <td class="costo"><xsl:value-of select="costo"/></td>
                                <td class="prezzoTotale">Calcolato tramite Javascript</td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="partecipante">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </td>     
                            </tr>

                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <h2 align="center" id="dataOdierna"></h2>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Studente</th>
                        <th>Quota</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="gruppo/studente[nome='sergio']/pagamenti/partecipante/id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="gruppo/studente[nome='sergio']/pagamenti/partecipante/quota"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <script src="contabilità.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The files are in the same directory.
I know that Chrome gives an error if the files are in local, but for the other two there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML and XSLT files are all correct. As you already noticed, Chrome doesn't work.
For Firefox, this behaviour is registered [as a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565261) which probably won't be fixed due to security concerns.

But you can circumvent this by modifying `about:config` in Firefox.
Set

```
privacy.file_unique_origin = false
```

Then you can at least use XMLs with local XSLTs in Firefox.
Disclaimer: I do not know about Edge :-(

Answer (score 1):

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="contabilità.xsl"?>` will work over HTTP(S), not from the file system. That is basically due to security restrictions browsers have imposed, some like Chrome long ago, others like Mozilla only recently as fixes to exploits in that area disregarded the use of XSLT from the file system or in case of Edge if you use the Chromium based new Edge as the browser engine has changed.

Comment: Note also, it's surprisingly easy to run a local web server on your machine that allows you to access local files over HTTP, which circumvents this restriction.