# Apply xsl:stylesheet to xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

Every time I create a xml file with its xsl file to apply on it a stylesheet I end up with a web page that does not consider the stylesheet.

Here is a simple example of the files:

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="student.xsl" version="2.0"?>
<class>
    <student>
        <firstname>First Name</firstname>
        <lastname>Last Name</lastname>
    </student>
</class>
```

**xsl file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match = "/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Student List</h2>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This is what appears on the web page:**

look at the image

Normally it should appear Student List and not First Name Last Name.

ps: I tried for browsers Firefox, Chrome, Microsoft Edge and I got the same problem.

Comment: The XML file and XSL file are used to generate output, for example HTML, but you need to call some processor to do the job. If your website supports PHP, write a PHP program calling the XSLTProcessor function with the XML and XSL files as input to produce the HTML output. See examples at https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtodoc.php

Comment: There are lots of questions/answers about browsers not executing stylesheets. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60709807/317052

Comment: Also, unless you're using SaxonJS, you're not going to get any browser to support XSLT greater than 1.0.

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you are doing. One common cause of problems is trying to run from the browser when the XML and/or XSLT are in local files, rather than being accessed via HTTP.

Comment: If you are looking for an easy way to transform the XML file for your own purposes, use Notepadd++ with XML tools to do the transform: https://www.herongyang.com/XML/NPP-XML-Tools-Plugin-XSLT-Transformation.html